# Webapp2 extract named parameters from route URL (without the Request, just the URL)

Tags: google-app-engine, routes, webapp2

I am using a route like the following in my app:

`Route(r'/thing/<some_id>/foo', handler=ThingFoo, name="thing-foo")`

This is used to generate a url using `uri_for('thing-foo', some_id="something")`, which is returned to the user which they store.
Then, in another request, the user posts the url returned to them previously, where it needs to be parsed.

I would like to extract the `<some_id>` pattern's value from the url provided in a similar way to how the router does it to pass the value to the RequestHandler's get/post methods, but the documentation on this seems to be lacking.

Is there something like the following?

```
route, some_id = webapp2.extract_uri(the_url)
```

(Of course I could extract the value directly using a regex, but that doesn't seem very DRY).

Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
def image_url(request, image_blob_key):
    if image_blob_key:
        return request.url_for('image', resource=image_blob_key, _full=True)
    else:
        return None

def blob_key_from_image_url(image_url):
    # Do something here to calculate the blob_key from the URL.
    return blob_key
```

In one part of my app, image_url is calculated from a blob_key and passed to the user. Later on if they (for example) want to delete the image, they pass the url back in a POST request, and I want to extract the blob_key from it so I can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
import webapp2

# somewhere in a request handler:
route = self.app.router.build_routes.get('my-route-name')
match = route.regex.match(the_url)
args, kwargs = webapp2._get_route_variables(match, route.defaults.copy())

# do something with args and kwargs, e.g. 
# thing = kwargs['thing-foo']
```

Source code: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2.html#Route

To be honest, I would simply pass blob_key to the template where users can delete an image, so that I could just build a URL beforehand, e.g.

```
uri_for('delete-image', image_key=some_blob_key)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Passing both the image fetch url and the delete url to the client is not ideal - I would prefer to have a single "id" string that gets passed around in order to fetch and delete the image on the client (an iOS app). I guess the best solution would be to use HTTP's DELETE method (instead of GET), but that would probably require some messing about with the routes and so on. I'm not sure if webapp2 supports PUT and DELETE out of the box.

Comment: FWIW webapp2 does support HTTP methods: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#restricting-http-methods And on the handler side you just do `def put(self, ...)` or `def delete(self, ...)`

Comment: Ah sorry, I think I got it now. You want to have single URL pattern match but run different code for e.g. `put` and `delete`. Yeah, I don't think that will work out of the box. Anyway, glad the above worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

I typically use this style.

Router :

```
Route('/auth/<provider>/call', handler='handlers.AuthHandler:meo', name='meo')
```

And handler class

```
class AuthHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def meo(self, provider=None):
    self.response.write(provider)
```

Comment: This only works for actual HTTP requests though. I don't want to call the request handler for a request, just extract the parameters from a URL. Sorry if that wasn't clear.